# Backing up in app purchases like gold or credits

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, backup

I have implemented in-app-purchases like Mission packs or "full version" before. However, I am now looking into selling in-game credits.

What are some ways of keeping track of spent and total credits, even after removing and reinstalling the app

Is it common to sync these totals between the different iOS devices of a single user? Or should a user re-buy credits on different devices?

Should I have a user register with my server and track the credit on there?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to keep track of user's data on your server. 
That way, even if the user deletes the app, the data will still be available after retrieving it from the server. Also, this will make you able to sync the same data between different platforms, not only devices.

After you retrieve the data, you might want to store it in NSUserDefaults and updated when needed.